# How can update Datagridview content when DataTable changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, datagridview

I want the DataGridView gets updated when DataTable changes (myAdapter.DeleteCommand = cmd;).

Please help me. Thanks

My code is:

1.

```
public void DoCommand(String commandText, ActionType actionType, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = getConnection();
        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);

        if (actionType == ActionType.Insert)
            myAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
        else if (actionType == ActionType.Update)
            myAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;
        else if (actionType == ActionType.Delete)
            myAdapter.DeleteCommand = cmd;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

2.

```
DataTable dt;
private void frmCustomers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = obj.SelectCustomer();
    dgCustomer.DataSource = localDt;
}
```

3.

```
private void btnDeleteCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
obj.DoCommand("delete from tbl_customer where customer_id = 1", ActionType.Delete);
}
```

Comment: clean the gridview before load the data

Comment: any way ?? i want refresh dt without select and fill again

Comment: Are you trying to remove the data from the database or just the copy of it loaded in as the DGV's source?